# RandomForest: Meaning of 'predicted' component and its relation to out-of-bag errors

Tags: r, random-forest

The explanation given for the predicted value of a random forest object is 'the predicted values of the input data based on out-of-bag samples'.

English is not my native language and I'm having trouble understanding this sentence. I'm currently working on a simulated regression problem using the random forest technique. The goal is to find the out-of-bag error for each sample in the simulation. After searching for a bit, I found this `predicted` component.

From what I understand from the sentence, for each tree, `predicted` returns that predicted value of the whole data subset that was **not** used for that particular tree. Suppose that I have N trees in the random forest, how many `predicted`-values will I get back?

Can the results of `predicted` be used as OOB prediction errors? Suppose that I have the value of `predicted` for the ith tree (`rf$predicted[i]`). Is the OOB error for the ith tree given by (rf$predicted[i] - response_of_tree_i)?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The i-th `predicted` value returns the mean of the predicted values across all trees that have the i-th value as OOB.

For example:

```
library(randomForest)
library(MASS)

set.seed(111)
rf = randomForest(medv ~ .,data=Boston,keep.forest=TRUE,keep.inbag=TRUE)

dim(Boston)
[1] 506  14

dim(rf$inbag)
[1] 506 500
```

So for the first observation, it is out of the bag in 198 trees:

```
table(rf$inbag[1,]==0)

FALSE  TRUE 
  302   198
```

If you like to get the prediction of all trees, you can use predict and then work out that the predicted value you see is the mean of i-th predictions in trees that have it as OOB:

```
allpred = predict(rf,newdata=Boston,predict.all=TRUE)$individual

rf$predicted[1]
       1 
28.70521 

mean(allpred[1,rf$inbag[1,]==0])
[1] 28.70521
```

Hence the predicted value can be used as OOB for the whole model, not for individual trees, because it is not of interest in a random forest model. You can also see this in the object, where `rf$mse` is the mean squared error with the i-th tree, so at 500 trees, you have the final mse of the model:

```
rf$mse[length(rf$mse)]
[1] 9.902396

mean((rf$predicted-rf$y)^2)
[1] 9.902396
```

If you would want to calculate the OOB error for each tree, bear in mind it is not the conventional OOB associated with random forest and you have to define it properly. You can also read about the random forest in this [introduction article](https://www.nature.com/articles/nmeth.4438)